# JQuery not looping through elements again

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, dom

I have the following code:

```
for(counter = 0; counter < 2; counter++) {
    $form = $("<form></form>");
    $form.append($('.mandatory-form-input'));

    if(counter == 0) {
        $form.append($('.upload_box:lt(10)'));
    } else {
        var start_point = (counter * 10) - 1;
        $form.append($('.upload_box:gt('+ start_point +'):lt(10)'));
    }

    console.log($form.html());
}
```

The logic I want to implement is that it should create a form, add all the mandatory inputs and then add inputs on parts (based on css, `lt`, `gt` thing)...

But this is not working as expected, on first iteration, it works properly, but on second iteration it does not console logs anything. I am not sure why... (Atleast it should show the added `mandatory-form-input` fields that I am appending), but it is not even showing that.

I want to ask, is there something that I am missing in my code? (Like, a way to reset some $ reference or something?)

Note: I tried clearing the $form variable at the end of the loop, it still didn't work...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are appending the same element `$('.mandatory-form-input')`, Then original element is removed from existing location and added to new `$form` object.

You can [`.clone()`](https://api.jquery.com/clone/) targeted element and then append them

> Create a deep copy of the set of matched elements.

```
for(counter = 0; counter < 2; counter++) {
    $form = $("<form></form>");
    $form.append($('.mandatory-form-input').clone()); //Affected line

    ....
    console.log($form.html());
}
```

Comment: Can you explain in a little bit more detail that why without clone it is not working?

Comment: @AayushSinha You are appending same element to multiple form, so when appending it is place to element where you just added

Comment: So that means that the original element is moved from the existing form to new one?

Comment: @AayushSinha Yes

Comment: Ah, I get it. Thanks.